# Error retrieving UserTransaction from EJBContext, throw IllegalStateException

Tags: java, jersey, websphere, illegalstateexception

I am trying to deploy an application in a websphere 8.5, the application deploys correctly but when trying to object the UserTransaction of the EJBContext I get an exception.

```
This is my code:
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
public class FooManagerBean implements FooManager {

    @Resource
    private EJBContext context;

    public FooManagerBean() {
    }

    //other methods

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public FooResponseDTO fooMethod(FooRequestDTO fooRequest) throws Exception {

        final UserTransaction userTx = context.getUserTransaction(); <- EXCEPTION!

        //other code & return

        return ...;
    }
```

And this is my log:

> [24/08/18 17:05:41:595 CEST] 000000b0 BusinessExcep E   CNTR0020E: EJB
>   ha generado una excepción no esperada (no declarada) al invocar el
>   método "fooMethod" en el bean
>   "BeanId(xxxxxxx#xxxxx.jar#FooManagerBean, null)". Datos de la
>   excepción:java.lang.IllegalStateException     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.CMStatelessBeanO.getUserTransaction(CMStatelessBeanO.java:79)
>     at com.xxx.....xxx.FooManagerBean.fooMethod(FooManagerBean.java:83)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invokeProceed(EJSContainer.java:5730)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:568)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:227)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:548)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.doAroundInvoke(InvocationContextImpl.java:229)
>     at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invoke(EJSContainer.java:5621)
>     at
>   com.xxx.....xxx.EJSLocal0SLFooManagerBean_7ca28fb0.fooMethod(EJSLocal0SLFooManagerBean_7ca28fb0.java)
>     at com.xxx.....xxx..FooService.fooMethod(FooService.java:37)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)

More trace:

> javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException   at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.util.ExceptionUtil.EJBException(ExceptionUtil.java:475)
>   ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.util.ExceptionUtil.EJBException(ExceptionUtil.java:365)
>   ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.mapException(BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.java:392)
>   ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.setUncheckedException(BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.java:554)
>   ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSDeployedSupport.setUncheckedLocalException(EJSDeployedSupport.java:567)
>   ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]  at
>   com.xxx.....xxx.EJSLocal0SLFooManagerBean_7ca28fb0.fooMethod(EJSLocal0SLFooManagerBean_7ca28fb0.java)
>     at com.xxx.....xxx..FooService.fooMethod(FooService.java:37)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.6.0]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   ~[na:1.6.0]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   ~[na:1.6.0]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>   ~[na:1.6.0]   at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>   [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
>   [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>   [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
>   [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>   [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>   [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>   [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>   [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
>   [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
>   [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
>   [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
>   [jersey-server-1.11.jar:1.11]     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
>   [jersey-servlet-1.11.jar:1.11]    at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
>   [jersey-servlet-1.11.jar:1.11]    at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
>   [jersey-servlet-1.11.jar:1.11]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
>   [javax.j2ee.servlet.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
>   [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
>   [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
>   [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>   [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>   [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
>   [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>   [spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>   [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>   [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
>   [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
>   [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
>   [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:909)
>   [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
>   [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
>   [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
>   [na:CCX.CF [o1103.02]]    at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
>   [na:CCX.CF [o1103.02]]    at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]   at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
>   [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na] Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: null     at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.CMStatelessBeanO.getUserTransaction(CMStatelessBeanO.java:79)
>   ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]  at
>   com.xxx.....xxx.FooManagerBean.fooMethod(FooManagerBean.java:83)
>   ~[xxxxx.jar:na]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.6.0]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   ~[na:1.6.0]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   ~[na:1.6.0]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>   ~[na:1.6.0]   at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invokeProceed(EJSContainer.java:5730)
>   ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:568)
>   ~[na:na]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.6.0]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   ~[na:1.6.0]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   ~[na:1.6.0]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>   ~[na:1.6.0]   at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InterceptorProxy.invokeInterceptor(InterceptorProxy.java:227)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:548)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.interceptors.InvocationContextImpl.doAroundInvoke(InvocationContextImpl.java:229)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invoke(EJSContainer.java:5621)
>   ~[com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]  ... 52 common frames omitted

And the content of the text file generated by the server:

> [24/08/18 13:59:04:518 CEST]     FFDC
>   Exception:java.lang.IllegalStateException
>   SourceId:com.ibm.ejs.container.BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy.setUncheckedException
>   ProbeId:506
>   Reporter:com.ibm.ejs.container.BusinessExceptionMappingStrategy@f138ac6b
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException   at
>   com.ibm.ejs.container.CMStatelessBeanO.getUserTransaction(CMStatelessBeanO.java:79)...
>   (the same again)

I have datasources declared in the websphere server that are correctly recovered in the application. Am I missing something to configure in the websphere?

Comment: You are confusing 2 transaction management methods. Either declare `TransactionManagementType.BEAN` which defines that bean will manage the transaction, or use `TransactionAttributeType.XXX` which requires container managed transactions. So either remove   `getUserTransaction()` method call or remove transation attributes. BTW. What are you trying to archive?

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem was that I created the ear with the version of java 1.8 and not with version 1.6. I have changed the version and deployed without this error. @Gas